# Creating Gist with PyGithub

Tags: python, pygithub

Is there an option to create new Gist with PyGithub?

There is such [API option](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) on GitHub, however it seems to be missing in [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Gist.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Github.get_user`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github.html#github.MainClass.Github.get_user) followed by [`AuthenticatedUser.create_gist`](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/AuthenticatedUser.html#github.AuthenticatedUser.AuthenticatedUser.create_gist):

```
gh = github.Github("auth token")
gh_auth_user = gh.get_user()
gist = gh_auth_user.create_gist(public=False, files={"myfile.txt": github.InputFileContent("my contents")}, description="my description")
```

Comment: do you happen to know how to *update* an existing gist?

Comment: Gist is a git repository. 


I'm cloning it locally after creation, then working with it like with regular git repo.